# How to determine Bash function state upon exit?

Tags: bash, function

While applying the [Google Shell Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html) on some bash code, I learned that I do not exactly know how to determine the exit state of a function. In particular, I was wondering whether any successful bash function returns the state 0, or whether it is only certain commands that ensure it returns state 0.

The example given:

```
#######################################
# Delete a file in a sophisticated manner.
# Arguments:
#   File to delete, a path.
# Returns:
#   0 if thing was deleted, non-zero on error.
#######################################
function del_thing() {
  rm "$1"
}
```

Describes the `rm` action, which apparently results in a state 0. However, I wonder whether all other commands that do not lead to an error also return state 0. (Excluding specific commands to set a specific return state like `exit 42`).

To find this out, I'd like to inspect the return state of certain functions. Yet I do not yet exactly know how to do that. Hence, I would like to ask: How do I print/see/inspect the return state of a function?

Comment: Aside: The syntax `function del_thing() {` mixes the POSIX sh form `del_thing() {` with the legacy ksh syntax `functon del_thing {` in a way that's incompatible with __both__ POSIX sh and legacy ksh. Much better to just use the POSIX form and skip the `function` keyword entirely; see also https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete (there are relevant entries in both the 1st and 3rd tables there).

Comment: (reading the style guide you linked, it has a mix of POSIX-compliant function declarations and incompatible-mismash ones; presence of the latter is leads to me advise against trusting it, even more than the internal inconsistency does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I print/see/inspect the return state

The variable `$?` hols the exit status of the previous command.

```
literally anything
echo "$?"

del_thing
echo "$?"
```

Note: do not use `$?` when checking for failure or success. Use `if`, like `if ! del_thing; then echo "it failed"; fi`.

Note: Do not use `function` with `()`. Just use `name() { .. }`, without `function`. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete . (https://github.com/google/styleguide/pull/624 ..)

> I wonder whether all other commands that do not lead to an error also return state 0

`0` exit status is considered success. Nonzero exit status is considered failure. For example, `if` expression checks if a command has a zero exit status - `if anything; then echo "anything exited with zero exit status"; fi`.

A function has the exit status of the last command executed. Usually, anything has the exit status of the last command executed. The exit status of `del_thing` function is *the same* as the exit status of `rm` command, because `rm` command is the last thing executed inside the function.